# libGDX actions: when they will execute

Tags: java, libgdx, action

My code:

```
actor.addAction(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.fadeOut(0.3f),
    Actions.run(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG,"after dispear");
    }
})));
actor.remove()
```

I found the action sequence will not execute at this time. If I add the actor again, it will. Can someone give me an explanation?

Comment: You are removing the actor, thats probably the reason :p

Answer (score 3):

```
actor.addAction(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.fadeOut(0.3f),
    Actions.run(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run() {
          Gdx.app.log(TAG,"after dispear");
       }
    }),
    Actions.removeActor()));
//actor.remove(); remove this line.
```

To remove an actor in an action chain use "Actions.removeActor"

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the actor to a stage, and then calling the act function?

Some more information or code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem comes from not understanding the concept of LibGDX actions.

If your goal is to perform actions in the order:

- fade out actor,
- log happened action,
- remove actor

then you have to append `actor.remove()` to the sequence.

Otherwise, when you leave the code as is two actor's methods:

- `addAction`,
- `remove`

will be executed one after another.

All the actions that you coded as a sequence (passed to `addAction` method) are designed to run asynchronously. The `addAction` method is non-blocking so, immediately after adding all the sequence to the actor's logic you are removing the whole actor and all magic have not enough time to evaluate.

Remove last line from the presented code and add [removeActor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html#removeActor--) action at the end of the sequence.